# hide content when div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a new site and I want to add a button that hides certain sections of the site when clicked. Right now I'm using the code below and it works fine but I just need it to do one more thing. How can I make it add a new class to the button when it's clicked so I can reposition the clicked button using css? Thanks in advance!

Here is the js code i'm using right now.

```
$(".hide-content").click(function() {
    $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500);
    });

$(".hide-content").toggle(function() {
      $(this).text("Hide");
    }, function() {
      $(this).text("Show");
    });
});
```

Comment: The bottom version of toggle() has been deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$(".hide-content").click(function() {
    $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500);
    $(this).addClass('ClassName'); //add class
});
```

---

Also Read [Class Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

---

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) has been [deprecated and removed](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Comment: This works great but how can I make it switch back to normal when it's clicked again?

Comment: @user3043983 Use `$(this).toggleClass('ClassName');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hide-content").click(function () {
    $(".hide-content").addClass("new-class")
    $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click', '.hide-content', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this);
    $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500, function () { //when complete..
        $el.addClass('myclass');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addClass` function

```
$(".hide-content").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("class-name")
  $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500);
});
```

Or you could do `css` directly on jquery using the `.css` function

```
$(".hide-content").click(function() {
  $(this).css("position", "absolute"); //note that params in css function is only an example, do what you need..
  $(".site-header, #page-entry, .site-footer").toggle(500);
});
```

Comment: How could I make it switch back when It's clicked again?